# Mysql comparing the values of two columns in the same row(s) in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been searching for a query to compare values in single rows in the same table.

Example table:

```sql
SKU        Description   SKU   Category  
173406926  Widgets       1734  
137406927  Widgets-Blue  1734
```

I need to find the rows where the SKU number does not start with the SKU Category number (as in row two above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   NOT (SKU LIKE CONCAT(`SKU Category`, '%'))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9f93/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

> SELECT * from tblName where SKU number REGEXP '^SKU Category'

Answer (score 0):

```
select sku from tablename t where not (sku like concat(`sku category`, '%'))
```

Try that...